# Error in data frame undefined columns selected

Tags: r

I've been working on an assignment where I have to read in some csv files from a directory "specdata". The files are very similar in that there are 332 titled 001.csv - 332.csv. They have consistent columns and headers, if that matters.

I believe I'm close but am tripping up with the above error message

> " Error in `[.data.frame`(data1, good) : undefined columns selected"

I had expected a data frame to load with all the data specified by the subset of files in id parameter.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {

              files <- list.files(directory)

              subsetFiles <- files[id]

              for (i in subsetFiles) {

                  filepaths <- paste(directory,"/",i, sep='')

                  data1 <- read.csv(filepaths)
                }

              data1

             good <- complete.cases(data1)

             data2 <- data1[good]

             data2
}

# test it out and ignore middle parameter for now
pollutantmean("specdata", "pass", 1:3)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you meaning?

```
data2 <- data1[good,]
```

With

```
data1[good]
```

you're selecting columns in a wrong way (using a logical vector of complete rows).

Consider that parameter `pollutant` is not used; is it a column name that you want to extract? if so it should be something like

```
data2 <- data1[good, pollutant]
```

Furthermore consider that you have to `rbind` the `data.frame`s inside the `for` loop, otherwise you get only the last data.frame (its completed.cases)

And last but not least, i'd prefer generating filenames eg with

```
id <- 1:322
paste0( directory, "/", gsub(" ", "0", sprintf("%3d",id)), ".csv")
```

A little modified chunk of `?sprintf`

The string `fmt` (in our case `"%3d"`) contains normal characters, which are passed through to the output string, and also **conversion specifications** which operate on the arguments provided through `...`. The allowed *conversion specifications start with a* `%` and end with one of the letters in the set `aAdifeEgGosxX%`. These letters denote the following types:

- `d`: integer

Eg a more general example

```
    sprintf("I am %10d years old", 25)
[1] "I am         25 years old"
          ^^^^^^^^^^
          |        |
          1       10
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I looked up sprintf in the documentation but really did not understand it. Will try your answer out when I get home

Comment: @DougFirr it makes a character vectors, each element of 3 char, right aligned, with numbers coming from id. After that i substitute all left spaces with 0

Comment: OK thanks. So the 3 in sprintf("%3d", presumably is the length of the vector but what are the "d" and % for?

Comment: thanks again @Luca for the example. I think I understand the logic in this example now. The use of nested formulas are tricky with this since it's new language to me, appreciated.